# Can the caller ignore async WCF call result?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous

I'm sure this must have been asked and answered, but I can't find it...

I have a WCF service with this interface:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = WcfNamespace.MyNamespace)]
public interface ILogging
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void LogInfo(string message);
}
```

In my (.NET 3.5) client application, I want to ignore any failure that happens during the call to `LogInfo` and I don't want to block, not even on the network transport.
Therefore, I'm thinking I should use one of the async patterns in my client. However, I can't figure out if there is any difference in how "ignore-the-result-friendly" the "event-based" or the "begin-end" patterns are. Is there a difference in this sense?
Or do you always have to implement a completed event or call `End*` anyway in order to not leak resources? (I vaguely recall reading something like that by either Skeet or Lippert)

Comment: by not calling the End method, you'll introduce a leak.  You don't need to use the value it returns, but you need to call it.

Comment: That's what I figured. I was kind of hoping for the WCF generated code to do something magical, I guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to implement any `*Completed` events if you're using the event-based async pattern, so that's an option. If you use the begin/end pattern, you should call the `End*` operation, and wrap it in a try/empty catch if you want to really ignore anything.